# Apache Performance SSL (rough estimate with "up to date" hardware)?

Tags: performance, ssl

I know this is not a good question, but I currently do not have any possibility to "performance test this" on my own, as I do not have access to any dedicated servers and I first have to buy one.

What are your experiences in Apache SSL performance (SSL-Requests per Seceond). I would be greatfull for some examples of you and/or an estimate what you think might be "out of the box" possible with a default installation of an Apache 2 with an SSL certificate on up to date hardware like an Intel Core i7-920 (4 Cores with 2,6 GHZ).

(With SSL Request I mean the First Request with all the SSL Handshaking and then 5 "follow up requests" with an establised SSL "Connection/Handshake") (Size of the Data is about 10KB) . How many Requests per Second are most likely possible with the hardware mentioned above. Or what where you possible to achieve with your hardware in your environment regarding SSL Performance).

(The Probelem is, I do not have any clue at all about SSL Performance. I read a lot that SSL connections are so much worse that I do not know if I can achieve with up to date hardware 10 Requests a Second or 200 or 2000. (With a standard apache WITHOUT SSL several thousand Requests per second should be possible?)

Thank you very much!!
jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without full specs on your machine it will be impossible to make any sort of statement as to how many requests per second Apache can serve.

What I can and will tell you, is that for serving static files (even with SSL) Apache on any modern piece of hardware will be able to saturate pretty much any network connection you can feed it. Apache is blisteringly fast for static files-you only start to see problems with serving files when you start to dynamically generate pages, or use lots of modules to modify the behavior of Apache.

Comment: Hello Josh, thank you very much. (In my eyes a Quad-Core CPU with 2,6 GHZ is a "modern piece of hardware" and if apache, run on such a machine, can saturate a 100MBit connection (even with only serving SSL Requests) than this is all I needed to know. Thanks for your answer. Jan